# How to compare a variable to a certain value, if it has the value the script should continue in CMD

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, variables, cmd

I have tried this code in my .batch file

```
@echo off
Title Ping
color b
echo Enter the website you would like to ping
set input=
set /p input= Enter your Website here:
color d
echo Enter the password for the program
set input2=
set /p input2= Enter the Pass here:
color b
IF [input2] EQU [1234]
```

It should check if `Input2` is equal to `1234` and if it is the script should continue, if it is not equal to `1234` it should just wait.

I guess it is pretty simple but I dont seem to get it working. Also script just crashes after the last line of code.

Comment: `EQU` is a numeric comparison operator. What you are doing with the `[]` would be for string comparisons to make sure a blank string won't work. Not only that but variables are used with `%%`, so `[input2]` would be changed to `%input2%`. No only this but there is no reason to define both input and input2 before the `set /p`, it is redundant

Comment: You need to use the search facility, there are thousands of examples on this site where input has been requested and that input has to meet a condition. Have you opened a Command Prompt window, typed `if /?`, and pressed the `[ENTER]` key, to read the usage information for that command? Did you know that when the end user is prompted for input using `set /p`, they could just press the `[ENTER]` key, or even worse type anything at all they want, including poison characters, or delibertately malicious strings? BTW, ignore the last statement in the previous comment, you should always define them.

Comment: Also, what do you need a password for running a `ping` command for?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i put some time into the code and i think im finished now.

```
@echo off
Title Ping
color b
echo Enter the website you would like to ping
set input=
set /p input= Enter your Website here:
set input2=
set /p input2= Enter Password here:
if /I "%input2%" NEQ "1234" GOTO END
setlocal
:PROMPT
set AREYOUSURE=
SET /P AREYOUSURE=Are you sure (Y/[N])?
IF /I "%AREYOUSURE%" NEQ "Y" GOTO END
set x=
set /p x= How many times you like to ping?
color c
cls
echo -------------------------------------------------------------
echo now pinging %input% %x% times press strg + c to cancel
echo -------------------------------------------------------------
color a
ping -l 65500 -n %x% %input%

:end 
endlocal
```